# is type=service-account affected by September 13, 2021 security update?

Tags: security, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I recently received this email from google:

> Hello Google Drive Developer,

> We have identified you as a Developer who has used the Drive API in the last 30 days. We are writing to let you know that on September 13, 2021, Drive will apply a security update that will change the links used to share some files, and may lead to some new file access requests. Access to files won’t change for people who have already viewed or modified these files.

> Please update your code as detailed below before September 13, 2021, to avoid failing requests.

> What do I need to know?
> Items that have a Drive API permission with type=domain or type=anyone, where withLink=true (v2) or allowFileDiscovery=false (v3), will be affected by this security update.

> In addition to the item ID, your application may now also need a resource key to access these items.

When I look at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing, the types are listed as:  (user, group, domain, or anyone) .
I'm using type=service-account for my shared google drive API access (no domain delegation enabled); which of those 4 types would 'service-account' fall under?
Or is the type=service-account not affected by this security update?

Comment: In my understanding the change only will affect google accounts (either a single user or group email accounts) as per https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/06/drive-file-link-updates.html. As for developers that uses Drive API permission, only the items that have a Drive API permission with type=domain or type=anyone, where withLink=true (v2) or allowFileDiscovery=false (v3), will be affected and I believe service accounts does not fall under these categories.

Comment: Thank you for that confirmation, @IrvinJayG. !